# Avoiding too many if else, else if statement for multiple(9) conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0, if-statement

I have got 9 condition for my if else statement , I was thinking is there any other alternative solution to make the code clean and short. All the 9 condition perform different calculations for asp.net mvc view . I have included the code and an image which shows the view of some conditions, hope it make sense , I was looking for any better and robust solution for this scenario.. thanks

```
//Condition 1
//when no selection is made for the 2 dropdownlist (garages & helmets)
if (formvalues["helmets"] == "" && formvalues["garages"] == "")
{
    ViewBag.hideHelmet = 1;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
    ViewBag.hideGarages = 1;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
    ViewBag.SelectedHelmets = 1;//
    ViewBag.SelectedGarages = 1;//
    ViewBag.TotalHelmets = 1;
    ViewBag.TotalGarages = 1;
    ViewBag.TotalAmount = 1;
    ViewBag.TotalAmount =  trackEventCost.UnitCost;
}
//Condition 2
//When garages are selected from dropdown & helmets are not selected
else if ((formvalues["helmets"] == "") && (Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["garages"]) > 0))
{
    ViewBag.hideHelmet = 0;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
    ViewBag.hideGarages = 1;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
    ViewBag.SelectedHelmets = 1;
    ViewBag.SelectedGarages = Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["garages"]);
    ViewBag.TotalHelmets = 1;
    ViewBag.TotalGarages = Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["garages"]) * getGarages.UnitCost;
    ViewBag.TotalAmount = ViewBag.TotalGarages + trackEventCost.UnitCost;
}
//Condition 3
//When helmets are selected from dropdown & garages are not selected
else if ((formvalues["garages"] == "") && (Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["helmets"]) > 0))
{
    ViewBag.hideHelmet = 1;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
    ViewBag.hideGarages = 0;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
    ViewBag.SelectedGarages = 1;
    ViewBag.SelectedHelmets = Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["helmets"]);
    ViewBag.TotalGarages = 1;
    ViewBag.TotalHelmets = Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["helmets"]) * getGarages.UnitCost;
    ViewBag.TotalAmount = ViewBag.TotalHelmets + trackEventCost.UnitCost;
}
//Condition 4
//When garages are not selected from dropdown & helmets dropdownlist is hidden on the view due to unavailablity of helmets for that event
else if (formvalues["garages"] == "" && (formvalues["helmets"] == null))
{
    ViewBag.hideHelmet = 1;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
    ViewBag.hideGarages = 1;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
    ViewBag.TotalAmount = trackEventCost.UnitCost;
}
//Condition 5
//When helmets are not selected from dropdown & garages dropdownlist is hidden on the view due to unavailablity of garages for that event
else if ((formvalues["garages"] == null) && (formvalues["helmets"] == ""))
{
    ViewBag.hideHelmet = 1;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
    ViewBag.hideGarages = 1;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
    ViewBag.SelectedHelmets = 1;
    ViewBag.TotalAmount = trackEventCost.UnitCost;
}
//Condition 6
//When both helmets and garages dropdown list is not displayed on the view as they are not present in the database
else if (formvalues["helmets"] == null && formvalues["garages"] == null)
{
    ViewBag.SelectedHelmets = 1;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
    ViewBag.SelectedGarages = 1;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
    ViewBag.TotalHelmets = 1;
    ViewBag.TotalGarages = 1;
    ViewBag.hideHelmet = 1;
    ViewBag.hideGarages = 1;
    ViewBag.TotalAmount = trackEventCost.UnitCost;
}
//Condition 7
//When garages are selected from dropdown & helmets dropdownlist is hidden on the view due to unavailablity of helmets for that event
else if (formvalues["helmets"] == null && Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["garages"]) > 0)
{
    ViewBag.hideHelmet = 0; //for jquery , This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
    ViewBag.hideGarages = 1; //for jquery , This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
    ViewBag.SelectedGarages = Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["garages"]);
    ViewBag.TotalGarages = Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["garages"]) * getGarages.UnitCost;
    ViewBag.TotalAmount = ViewBag.TotalGarages + trackEventCost.UnitCost;
}
//Condition 8
//When helmets are selected from dropdown & garages dropdownlist is hidden on the view due to unavailablity of garages for that event
else if (Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["helmets"]) > 0 && formvalues["garages"] == null)
{
    ViewBag.hideHelmet = 1; //for jquery , This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
    ViewBag.hideGarages = 0; //for jquery , This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
    ViewBag.TotalHelmets = Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["helmets"]) * getHelmets.UnitCost;
    ViewBag.TotalAmount = ViewBag.TotalHelmets + trackEventCost.UnitCost;
}
//Condition 9
//When garages and helmet both dropdown are selected
 else
{
    ViewBag.hideHelmet = 0;//for jquery , This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
    ViewBag.hideGarages = 0;//for jquery , This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
    ViewBag.SelectedHelmets = Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["helmets"]);
    ViewBag.SelectedGarages = Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["garages"]);
    ViewBag.TotalHelmets = Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["helmets"]) * getHelmets.UnitCost;
    ViewBag.TotalGarages = Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["garages"]) * getGarages.UnitCost;
    ViewBag.TotalAmount = ViewBag.TotalHelmets + ViewBag.TotalGarages + trackEventCost.UnitCost;
}
```

[image: Some Conditions]

Comment: It looks like what is happening with the helmets does not change anything you do for garages (independent operations => use 2 case statements).  So you only need to do 3+3=6 checks instead of 3*3=9 checks.  Also confused...you have two different variables with the same comment, and it is the only thing that looks different between the empty string and null case.

Comment: I suggest you to study a bit about how to avoid too many ifs, because it is your second question related with that.

Comment: @yeh Renius , But i didnt got a better answer on it , so i explained this one in brief with images, nd got too many answers , will study all the solutions thnx everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, move the extraction of the form value to the beginning of the method, e.g:

```
int? helmets = formvalues["helmets"] == null ?
  null : Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["helmets"];
int? garages = formvalues["garages"] == null ?
  null : Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["garages"];
```

Then you can probably very easily set the properties without any ifs/else ifs, e.g:

```
ViewBag.hideHelmet = helmets;
// or
someOtherProperty = helmets == null ? ... : ...
```

Update (regarding your comment/question):

- The `?:` operator in the statement `x = condition ? value1 : value2` is called [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx). It returns `value1` if `condition` is true, and `value2` otherwise.
- `int?` is a [nullable integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), which can either have an integer value or be null.

Comment: can you please explain me statement : int? helmets = formvalues["helmets"] == null ?
  null : Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["helmets"];

Comment: `int?` is a nullable integer: if no formvalue with key "helmets" is found, `helmets` is set to null, otherwise to the value found in formvalues.

Comment: You can then check whether helmets has a value or not: `if helmets.HasValue ...`

Comment: @Mr A If you are having trouble understanding the syntax, look at the msdn documentation for conditional statements like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Comment: The correct condition is this : int? checkGarages = formvalues["garages"] == null ? (int?)null : Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["garages"]);

Answer (score 5):

Certainly 1 thing you could do is improve how you write your conditionals.  I think you might be better served by extracting your conditionals into methods to describe what the check is actually doing instead of adding comments everywhere.

Comment: The OP could extract the statements within the if-blocks into their own methods as well. That would clean up the code significantly.

Comment: all the condition do some calculation , for instance in condition 1 , nothing is selected , therefore no calculation is made and both the dropdown list will be hidden when the page is posted . Also the only totalprice for quantity without any addition price of helmets or garages as they r not selected .

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you focus on the assignment targets, instead of the conditions?

The condidition seems to be pretty simple and repeated. One sample:

```
ViewBag.hideHelmet = formvalues["helmets"] == ""? 1 : 0;
```

This doesn't need any branching logic.

Comment: can u explain the operator you using above please

Comment: @Mr A: `condition ? first_expression : second_expression;` is the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could move

```
ViewBag.hideHelmet = 1;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show             
ViewBag.hideGarages = 1;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show             
ViewBag.SelectedHelmets = 1;//             
ViewBag.SelectedGarages = 1;//             
ViewBag.TotalHelmets = 1;             
ViewBag.TotalGarages = 1;             
ViewBag.TotalAmount = 1;             
ViewBag.TotalAmount =  trackEventCost.UnitCost;
```

To a method with certain parameter as `optional` because you dont set all the values in all cases. Secondly you could use [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). You could use ternary operators like.

```
  int r = 1;
  long l = r == 1 ? 1 : (r==2 ? 2 : (r==3?3:(r==4 ? 4 : 5)));
```

Comment: have u got any gud tutorial for ternary operators

Comment: Please look at the link in my answer.

Comment: @Abdul Muqtadir, From my point of view, the complex ternary operator you've posted makes code less readable

Comment: 'ternary operator' is the link, its not redirecting to my profile.

Answer (score 1):

You could abstract your ViewBag to a function that sets all of your data.  This will clean things up a bit., e.g.

```
if(...) {
   SetUpViewBag(...); }
else {
   SetUpViewBag(...); }

...

private SetUpViewBag(...)
{
   ViewBag.SelectedHelmets = prop1;
   ViewBag.SelectedGarages = prop2;
   ViewBag.TotalHelmets = prop3;
   ViewBag.TotalGarages = prop4;
   ViewBag.hideHelmet = prop5;
   ViewBag.hideGarages = prop6;
   ViewBag.TotalAmount = prop7;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [Factory Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFactory.aspx#_self1) to generate your `ViewBag` object based on the conditions.  Have the factory generate the desired `ViewBag` and assign your object to that.

Here is an example in a console example (just for quick demonstration):

```
  class MainApp
  {
     /// <summary>
     /// Entry point into console application.
     /// </summary>
     static void Main()
     {
        ViewBagCreator creator = new ConcreteCreatorForViewBagObject();

        string garages_form_value = ""; // formvalues["garages"];
        string helmets_form_value = ""; // formvalues["helments"];

        // create viewpage
        ViewBagObject view_bag = creator.FactoryMethod(helmets_form_value,
           garages_form_value, 10, 100, 23);
        Console.WriteLine("Created {0}",
          view_bag.GetType().Name);

        // Assign your viewbag object here
        // ViewBag = view_bag;

        // Wait for user
        Console.ReadKey();
     }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// The 'ViewBagObject' abstract class
  /// </summary>
  abstract class ViewBagObject
  {
     public int hideHelmet;
     public int hideGarages;
     public int SelectedHelmets;
     public int SelectedGarages;
     public int TotalHelmets;
     public int TotalGarages;
     public int TotalAmount;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// A 'ViewBagNoSelection' class
  /// </summary>
  class ViewBagNoSelection : ViewBagObject
  {
     public ViewBagNoSelection(int trackEventUnitCost)
     {
        hideHelmet = 1;
        hideGarages = 1;
        SelectedHelmets = 1;
        SelectedGarages = 1;
        TotalHelmets = 1;
        TotalGarages = 1;
        TotalAmount = trackEventUnitCost;
     }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// A 'ViewBagGaragesNoHelments' class
  /// </summary>
  class ViewBagGaragesNoHelments : ViewBagObject
  {
     public ViewBagGaragesNoHelments(int garagesValue, int garagesUnitCost, int trackEventUnitCost)
     {
        hideHelmet = 0;
        hideGarages = 1;
        SelectedHelmets = 1;
        SelectedGarages = garagesValue;
        TotalHelmets = 1;
        TotalGarages = garagesValue * garagesUnitCost;
        TotalAmount = TotalGarages * trackEventUnitCost;
     }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// A 'ViewBagHelmentsNoGarages' class
  /// </summary>
  class ViewBagHelmentsNoGarages : ViewBagObject
  {
     public ViewBagHelmentsNoGarages(int helmetsValue, int helmentsUnitCost, int trackEventUnitCost)
     {
        hideHelmet = 0;
        hideGarages = 1;
        SelectedHelmets = helmetsValue;
        SelectedGarages = 1;
        TotalHelmets = helmetsValue * helmentsUnitCost;
        TotalGarages = 1;
        TotalAmount = TotalHelmets * trackEventUnitCost;
     }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// The 'ViewBagCreator' abstract class
  /// </summary>
  abstract class ViewBagCreator
  {
     public abstract ViewBagObject FactoryMethod(
        string helmetsFormValue, string garagesFormValue,
        int helmetsUnitCost, int garagesUnitCost, int trackEventUnitCost);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// A 'ConcreteCreator' class
  /// </summary>
  class ConcreteCreatorForViewBagObject : ViewBagCreator
  {
     public override ViewBagObject FactoryMethod(
        string helmetsFormValue, string garagesFormValue,
        int helmetsUnitCost, int garagesUnitCost, int trackEventUnitCost)
     {
        bool helmets_value_is_null = (helmetsFormValue == null);
        bool helmets_value_is_empty = (helmetsFormValue == "");
        bool garages_value_is_null = (garagesFormValue == null);
        bool garages_value_is_empty = (garagesFormValue == "");

        int helmets = 0;
        int garages = 0;
        int.TryParse(garagesFormValue, out garages);
        int.TryParse(helmetsFormValue, out helmets);

        bool garages_greater_than_zero = garages > 0;
        bool helmets_greater_than_zero = helmets > 0;

        if (helmets_value_is_empty && garages_value_is_empty)
        {
           return new ViewBagNoSelection(trackEventUnitCost);
        }
        else if (helmets_value_is_empty && garages_greater_than_zero)
        {
           return new ViewBagGaragesNoHelments(garages, garagesUnitCost, trackEventUnitCost);
        }
        else if (garages_value_is_empty && helmets_greater_than_zero)
        {
           return new ViewBagHelmentsNoGarages(helmets, helmetsUnitCost, trackEventUnitCost);
        }
        //...
        return null;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern, for your case you have to use method per strategy rather than class per strategy.

```
void ApplyStrategy(int? helmets, int? garages)
{
 // depends on values of helmets and garages execute appropriate strategy
}

void ApplyNoHelmetsNoGaragesStrategy()
void ApplyNoGaragesStrategy()
void ApplyNoHelmetsStrategy()
// ...
```

Comment: Although you are right about the Strategy pattern, I don't think this will help the OP. Try giving an example of how the OP can refactor his code with the strategy pattern.

Comment: Too many answers , i have to work through all the answers and see which one is better , I wish i was gud at csharp..

Answer (score 1):

What about building a condition class

```
public class Condition
{
    public Func<bool> Match { get; set; }
    public Action Execute { get; set; }
}
```

and bulid a list

```
        var conditions = new List<Condition>
        {
            new Condition
                {
                    Match = () => formvalues["helmets"] == "" && formvalues["garages"] == "",
                    Action = () =>
                                 {
                                      ViewBag.hideHelmet = 1;    
                                      ViewBag.hideGarages = 1;
                                      ViewBag.SelectedHelmets = 1;
                                      ...
                                 }
                },
            new Condition
                { 
                  ...
                }
         };
```

then linq:

```
   conditions.Where(c => c.Match()).ToList().ForEach( c => c.Execute());
```

Answer (score 1):

Some great suggestions. I like to handle these situations as follows.  I've refactored your code to remove the conditionals entirely.  Instead I've encapsulated the code for each condition into a method and created a hashtable with a key of type `int` and a value of type `Action`.  I've derived a unique value for each helmet/garage combination which is then used as the key for the corresponding method.

I've included dummy implementations for the bits of code not in your post so that I could compile and run my refactored example.  Hope that helps.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public enum HelmetState { Null = 1, Empty = 2, HasValue = 3 }
    public enum GarageState { Null = 4, Empty = 5, HasValue = 6 }

    public class ReducingConditionals
    {
        private TrackEventCost trackEventCost = new TrackEventCost();
        private GetHelmets getHelmets = new GetHelmets();
        private GetGarages getGarages = new GetGarages();
        private IDictionary<int, Action> ExecuteCondition;

        //the formvalues collection
        private Hashtable _formvalues;
        public Hashtable formvalues{ get { return _formvalues ?? (_formvalues = new Hashtable()); } }

        //set up dictionary of Actions
        public ReducingConditionals()
        {
            ExecuteCondition = new Dictionary<int, Action>();
            ExecuteCondition[Key(HelmetState.Null, GarageState.Null)] = HelmetsNullGaragesNull;
            ExecuteCondition[Key(HelmetState.Null, GarageState.Empty)] = HelmetsNullGaragesEmpty;
            ExecuteCondition[Key(HelmetState.Null, GarageState.HasValue)] = HelmetsNullGaragesHasValue;
            ExecuteCondition[Key(HelmetState.Empty, GarageState.Null)] = HelmetsEmptyGaragesNull;
            ExecuteCondition[Key(HelmetState.Empty, GarageState.Empty)] = HelmetsEmptyGaragesEmpty;
            ExecuteCondition[Key(HelmetState.Empty, GarageState.Empty)] = HelmetsEmptyGaragesHasValue;
            ExecuteCondition[Key(HelmetState.HasValue, GarageState.Empty)] = HelmetsHasValueGaragesNull;
            ExecuteCondition[Key(HelmetState.HasValue, GarageState.Null)] = HelmetsHasValueGaragesEmpty;
            ExecuteCondition[Key(HelmetState.HasValue, GarageState.HasValue)] = AnyOtherCondition;
        }

        //gets a unique value for each HelmetState/GarageState combination to be used as a key to the dictionary
        private int Key(HelmetState helmetState, GarageState garageState)
        {
            return (int)helmetState + (int)garageState;
        }

        //Execute the appropriate method - n.b. no if statements in sight!
        public void DealWithConditions()
        {
            HelmetState helmetState = GetHelmetState(formvalues["helmets"]);
            GarageState garageState = GetGarageState(formvalues["garages"]);
            ExecuteCondition[Key(helmetState, garageState)]();
        }

        //assign helmet state enum
        private HelmetState GetHelmetState(object helmetValue)
        {
            if (helmetValue == null) return HelmetState.Null;
            if (helmetValue.ToString() == "") return HelmetState.Empty;
            if (Convert.ToInt32(helmetValue) > 0) return HelmetState.HasValue;
            throw new InvalidDataException("Unexpected parameter value");
        }

        //assign garage state enum
        private GarageState GetGarageState(object garageValue)
        {
            if (garageValue == null) return GarageState.Null;
            if (garageValue.ToString() == "") return GarageState.Empty;
            if (Convert.ToInt32(garageValue) > 0) return GarageState.HasValue;
            throw new InvalidDataException("Unexpected parameter value");
        }

        #region encapsulate conditions in methods
        private void AnyOtherCondition()
        {
            ViewBag.hideHelmet = 0;//for jquery , This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
            ViewBag.hideGarages = 0;//for jquery , This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
            ViewBag.SelectedHelmets = Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["helmets"]);
            ViewBag.SelectedGarages = Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["garages"]);
            ViewBag.TotalHelmets = Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["helmets"]) * getHelmets.UnitCost;
            ViewBag.TotalGarages = Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["garages"]) * getGarages.UnitCost;
            ViewBag.TotalAmount = ViewBag.TotalHelmets + ViewBag.TotalGarages + trackEventCost.UnitCost;
        }

        private void HelmetsHasValueGaragesNull()
        {
            ViewBag.hideHelmet = 1; //for jquery , This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
            ViewBag.hideGarages = 0; //for jquery , This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
            ViewBag.TotalHelmets = Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["helmets"]) * getHelmets.UnitCost;
            ViewBag.TotalAmount = ViewBag.TotalHelmets + trackEventCost.UnitCost;
        }

        private void HelmetsNullGaragesHasValue()
        {
            ViewBag.hideHelmet = 0; //for jquery , This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
            ViewBag.hideGarages = 1; //for jquery , This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
            ViewBag.SelectedGarages = Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["garages"]);
            ViewBag.TotalGarages = Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["garages"]) * getGarages.UnitCost;
            ViewBag.TotalAmount = ViewBag.TotalGarages + trackEventCost.UnitCost;
        }

        private void HelmetsNullGaragesNull()
        {
            ViewBag.SelectedHelmets = 1;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
            ViewBag.SelectedGarages = 1;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
            ViewBag.TotalHelmets = 1;
            ViewBag.TotalGarages = 1;
            ViewBag.hideHelmet = 1;
            ViewBag.hideGarages = 1;
            ViewBag.TotalAmount = trackEventCost.UnitCost;
        }

        private void HelmetsEmptyGaragesNull()
        {
            ViewBag.hideHelmet = 1;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
            ViewBag.hideGarages = 1;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
            ViewBag.SelectedHelmets = 1;
            ViewBag.TotalAmount = trackEventCost.UnitCost;
        }

        private void HelmetsNullGaragesEmpty()
        {
            ViewBag.hideHelmet = 1;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
            ViewBag.hideGarages = 1;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
            ViewBag.TotalAmount = trackEventCost.UnitCost;
        }

        private void HelmetsHasValueGaragesEmpty()
        {
            ViewBag.hideHelmet = 1;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
            ViewBag.hideGarages = 0;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
            ViewBag.SelectedGarages = 1;
            ViewBag.SelectedHelmets = Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["helmets"]);
            ViewBag.TotalGarages = 1;
            ViewBag.TotalHelmets = Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["helmets"]) * getGarages.UnitCost;
            ViewBag.TotalAmount = ViewBag.TotalHelmets + trackEventCost.UnitCost;
        }

        private void HelmetsEmptyGaragesHasValue()
        {
            ViewBag.hideHelmet = 0;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
            ViewBag.hideGarages = 1;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
            ViewBag.SelectedHelmets = 1;
            ViewBag.SelectedGarages = Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["garages"]);
            ViewBag.TotalHelmets = 1;
            ViewBag.TotalGarages = Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["garages"]) * getGarages.UnitCost;
            ViewBag.TotalAmount = ViewBag.TotalGarages + trackEventCost.UnitCost;
        }

        private void HelmetsEmptyGaragesEmpty()
        {
            ViewBag.hideHelmet = 1;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
            ViewBag.hideGarages = 1;//for jquery, This value is passed to jquery script which then decides which field to hide/show
            ViewBag.SelectedHelmets = 1;//
            ViewBag.SelectedGarages = 1;//
            ViewBag.TotalHelmets = 1;
            ViewBag.TotalGarages = 1;
            ViewBag.TotalAmount = 1;
            ViewBag.TotalAmount = trackEventCost.UnitCost;
        }
        #endregion
    }

    #region dummy class class implementations
    public class ViewBag
    {
        public static int TotalAmount;
        public static int hideHelmet { get; set; }
        public static int hideGarages { get; set; }
        public static int SelectedHelmets { get; set; }
        public static int SelectedGarages { get; set; }
        public static int TotalGarages { get; set; }
        public static int TotalHelmets { get; set; }
    }
    internal class GetGarages { public int UnitCost; }
    internal class GetHelmets { public int UnitCost; }
    internal class TrackEventCost{ public int UnitCost;}
    #endregion
}
```